# Android Drawable Drawing Performance?

Tags: android, performance, drawing, drawable

In my view I have a simple ARGB drawable that takes about 2ms to draw but I can draw the same file as a bitmap in under 0.5ms (just some quick code, I can't really consider it an option). What are the best ways to optimize the drawing speed of a drawable?

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the number of drawables and how many times each gets drawn.  For a small number, use canvas (an exact number will also depend on the device) I would suggest using [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) as it's a nice higher level approach to drawing.

If you want to crank out a lot of images (think hundreds), I would suggest creating a [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) and using openGL to render your images using VBOs tailored to your app.  I would also recommend using a texture sheet if you go down this route since you'll get a huge increase in performance at the cost of code complexity.

But this will also depend on that type of app.  My background is in game development so I use openGL exclusively for better performance.  for a simple app (something along the lines of androidify) Canvas should be fine.  If you want a simple tutorial for openGL, I suggest visiting Bergman's series of posts on the topic (google should give you a link for that).  It is a nice intro to openGL.

Comment: OpenGLES in Android doesn't support GLUtilities. In this case, we could not use tessellation for concave polygons. Also, drawing 2D with OpenGL, the threading is an issue. Do you have any recommendation for that?