# ShapeDrawable Vs Png images in android app

Tags: android, android-resources

Difference when using shape drawable or png images in res folder of android app structure

Which one is better on performance ,apk size and drawing complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on your number of drawables ,i would simply suggest you to use Image drawable (.png),

here is some suggested links:

[Performance wise, what is typically better, using an image or a xml created shape as a drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147073/2173753)

[Android Drawable Drawing Performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915946/2173753)

Comment: But usage of resources adds up to the size of apk which would make the app heavy .Right ?

Comment: right but If you use PNG format, PNG images can be reduced in file size without losing quality. To do this, use a tool such as OptiPNG or PNGCrush. Both are great for reducing PNG file size while still ensuring image quality. PNGcrush is an open-source program that iterates over PNG filters and zlib (Deflate) parameters, compresses the image repeatedly using each parameter configuration. and OptiPNG performs the trials entirely in memory, and writes only the final output file on the disk. Moreover, it offers multiple optimization presets to the user.